# I am getting a syntax error in python using flask and I have no idea why

Tags: python, html, flask

This is a simple python file that is meant to send a user to a page only if using the POST method, and if not just redirect them to the 'login' page. I'm using Sublime and it is highlighting the return statement as an error. When I run my file in the command prompt I also get an error

else:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Here is my code...

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, session

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/login", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["nm"]
        session["user"] = user
        return redirect(url_for("user")
    else :
        return render_template("login.html")
## I am getting a syntax error on the two lines above, specifically on the 'else' statement.

@app.route("/user")
def user(usr):
    if "user" in session:
        user = session["user"]
        return f"<h1>{user}</h1>"
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You're missing a close paren on the line `return redirect(url_for("user")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close the `return redirect(url_for("user")` second bracket in line 14.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a close paren on the line `return redirect(url_for("user")`